# JSON to AVRO deserialization in KSQL error : Skipping record due to deserialization error

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have set up a confluent platform on AWS. My source is MySql and I have connected it to Kafka connect using the debezium connector. The data format from the source is JSON. Now in KSQL, I have created a derived topic and converting the JSON topic to AVRO to make the data feasible to get sank to MYSQL using JDBC connector. I have used the following queries :

```
CREATE STREAM json_stream (userId int, auth_id varchar, email varchar) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

derived topic:

```
create TABLE avro_stream WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS select * from json_stream;
```

I have tried to use JSON message directly to sink to mysql but it fails as the connector needs schema so either JSON with schema or Avro message would help me to sank data.

While consuming from the topic avro_stream :

```
 [2019-07-09 13:27:30,239] WARN task [0_3] Skipping record due to
 deserialization error. topic=[avro_stream] partition=[3] offset=[144]
 (org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer:86)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: avro_stream     at
 io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:97)
    at
 io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlConnectDeserializer.java:44)
    at
 io.confluent.ksql.serde.connect.KsqlConnectDeserializer.deserialize(KsqlConnectDeserializer.java:26)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:63)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:97)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:117)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:638)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addRecordsToTasks(StreamThread.java:936)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:831)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at
 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
 Error deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
 byte!
```

My debezium connector config :

```
{
"name": "debezium-connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "database.user": "XXXXX",
    "auto.create.topics.enable": "true",
    "database.server.id": "1",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "X.X.X.X:9092",,
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "XXXXXXX",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "database.server.name": "XX-server",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "table.whitelist": "XXXX.XXXX",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "database.hostname": "X.X.X.X",
    "database.password": "xxxxxxx",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "debezium-connector",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.whitelist": "XXXXX",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
},
"tasks": [
    {
        "connector": "debezium-connector",
        "task": 0
    }
],
"type": "source"
```

}

Comment: (1) can you include the source connector (Debezium) config in your question (2) Why aren't you just using Avro from the source, then you don't need to reserialise?

Comment: I have tried AVRO from the source but faced serialization issues in executing queries in KSQL. As I am new to Kafka, so I changed my source data format to JSON  and get the KSQL queries to get worked. I am mentioning the source connector (Debezium) config.

Comment: If you're new to this then take my word for it : Use Avro from the outset. Mixing & matching JSON/Avro is a recipe for disaster. If you can't get Avro working from source, then post a question here and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Ok, I will try again with Avro from the source . But still, want to know what's wrong with the above setup.

Answer (score 1):

KSQL writes keys as `STRING`, so whilst you're using Avro for your value serialisation, the keys are not. Therefore your Sink worker needs to be configured thus:

```
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<url to schema registry>",
```

If you've configured your worker itself to use Avro then you can override just the `key.converter` for your Connector configuration.